# How to transform Array[RDD[Row]] to SchemaRDD -- OR -- how to split SchemaRDD, in which the results be SchemaRDDs?

Tags: scala, split, apache-spark, rdd

I want to use the implementation of pipeline in MLlib. To use pipeline, there should be sequence of LabeledDocument to be passed to the pipeline (*SchemaRDD*).

I create SchemaRDD as follows:

```
val data = sc.textFile("/test.csv");
val parsedData = data.map { line =>
        val parts = line.split(',')
        LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts.tail))
        }.cache()
val rddSchema = parsedData.toSchemaRDD;
```

I want to split the new *rddSchema* into training (80%) and test (20%). If I use *randomSplit*, it returns a *Array[RDD[Row]]* instead of *SchemaRDD*.

**Problem**: How to transform *Array[RDD[Row]]* to *SchemaRDD*

-- OR --

How to split *SchemaRDD*, in which the results be *SchemaRDDs*?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but did you try that :

```
val splits = parsedData.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), seed = 11L)
val training = splits(0)
val test = splits(1)
```